# Speech to Text considerations for custom .net app

Tags: .net, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am a .Net 3.5 WinForm app that is used for Data Entry in house only.  Mostly various forms of Textboxes etc.  With Windows 7 Speech Recognition it *seems* like it works "out of the box" with my app for me.

What I am wondering is if that is completely true.  What steps do I need to take to ensure the highest level of usability in my app?  Does it use tags for the UI elements or something else.

Do I need to inclued the `System.Speech.Recognition Namespace` talked about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx)

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Primarily, how to give an element a particular handle for Speech Recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Speech Recognition uses Text Services Framework for dictation; Text Services Framework has built-in support for all Win32 plain edit and RichEdit controls, and the WPF Textbox has support for Text Services Framework as well.   So if your WinForms app uses standard Textboxes, or if it uses custom Textboxes that wrap a Win32 richedit or plain edit control, Windows Speech Recognition will work fine.

If you also need command & control, then you need to make sure that your controls have the correct accessibility properties.  Mostly, all you need to do is make sure that your controls all have AccessibleName properties set; the AccessibleRole property should almost certainly be left at 'Default'.